# Cant sign_in/login_as in feature test devise capybara rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I have been bashing my skull for the past 4 hours.

So basicly i cant login/sign in as a user in my feature test, i am using devise_auth_token gem.

Feature test:

```
  1 require 'rails_helper'
  2     
  3 # TODO: rename unit to features
  4 feature 'Access' do
  5   before :each do
  6     @user = Fabricate :user
  7     @user.confirm
  8   
  9     @post = Fabricate :post, user: @user
 10     Fabricate :note, post: @post 
 11   end
 12 
 13   it 'should show error if not loged in' do
 14     visit api_posts_path
 15     expect(page).to have_content '{"errors":["Authorized users only."]}'
 16   end
 17 
 18   it 'should let all user roles view list of posts', format: :js do
 19     login_as @user, scope: :user
 20     visit api_posts_path
 21     binding.pry
```

My spec helper:

```
    require 'database_cleaner'
require 'devise'
require 'auth'

include Devise::TestHelpers                          
include Warden::Test::Helpers

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.before :suite do
    Warden.test_mode!
  end

  config.include AuthHelper

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

It gives me that the user is not authorized.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'pry-awesome_print'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'fabrication'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end

gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rack-cors'
```

Comment: Some1 ? I am in horror here

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec) have you checked this?

Comment: Yes, have gone it trought and trought!

Comment: Also, I didnt find the solution, i just droped feature tests and made unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific error you're having I think the most likely cause here is that you don't have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in your spec_helper, which would mean you're still running with transactional database access in your tests and any objects you create in your tests won't actually be visible to the app in `js: true` tests.  A second issue (not causing this problem) is that you aren't calling `Warden.test_reset!` in an after block.

The bigger issue here is you appear to be using Capybara to test an API, [which Capybara isn't designed for](http://www.elabs.se/blog/34-capybara-and-testing-apis). You probably want to using request specs to test an API.

Comment: Tryed all that, didnt help ;?